# How to bypass alert/dialog authentication in POST request?

Tags: rest, web, post, request, postman

So, when I try to consume certain API i got this screen

[image: screen from the Correios API]

I want to know if there's a way I can send this "username" and "password" through postman or javascript.

When I try to use postman i get 401 unauthorized

[image: postman request unauthorized]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found that I have to encode as base64 the username:password and use the generated token as "Authorization" in the headers of the request.